# Python formatted string using list range

Tags: python, python-3.x, format

I have been researching a lot of questions about It on stackOverflow and google. But none of then solved my problem.

Let's say, I have an irregular length string (like a phone number or specific and territorial documents) for example:

```
docA="A123B456"
docB="A123B456CD"
docC="6CD"
```

I'm writing a function to print documents. But they don't have a definite pattern, my approach was to use a default variable using the most common pattern and give the responsibility of corner cases to the programmer.
e.g:

```
def printDoc(text, pattern="{}{}{}{}#{}{}{}-{}")
    print(pattern.format(*text))
```

But It would be much more clean and explicit if there's a way to simplify the pattern like

```
def printDoc(text, pattern="{0:3}#{4:-1}-{-1}")
    print(pattern.format(*text))
```

Then I could use It like:

```
printDoc(docA)
printDoc(docB)
printDoc(docC, "{0:1}-{2}")
```

But It's not a valid syntax. Is there a way of doing this properly?

If my approach is wrong, is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use regular expression to parse the indexes/slices from the format string and use those to index given text. You'd also have to remove the indeces from format string before using it with `str.format`. The only tricky part is actually getting format parameters out from `text` but if you consider [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#eval) acceptable you could do following:

```
import re

def printDoc(text, pattern="{0:3}#{4:-1}-{-1}"):
    params = []

    # Find occurrences of '{}' from format string and extract format parameter
    for m in re.finditer(r'\{([-:\d]+)\}', pattern):
        params.append(eval('text[{}]'.format(m.group(1))))

    # Remove indeces from format string
    pattern = re.sub(r'\{([-:\d]+)\}', '{}', pattern)
    print(pattern.format(*params))

printDoc('A123B456')
```

Output:

```
A12#B45-6
```

Note that using `eval` is generally considered [bad and unsafe practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/is-using-eval-in-python-a-bad-practice). Although the potential risks are limited here because of restricted character set given to `eval` you might want to consider other alternatives unless you're the one who controls the format strings.

Comment: Thank you for comment, but I can't use eval =(

Comment: @EricLopes You could still use the same principle with `regex` that captures either one or two numbers and then uses those to index/slice `text`.